# In Google App Engine, how to check input validity of Key created by urlsafe?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Suppose I create a key from user input websafe url

```
key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=some_user_input)
```

How can I check if the `some_user_input` is valid?

My current experiment shows that statement above will throw `ProtocolBufferDecodeError (Unable to merge from string.)` exception if the `some_user_input` is invalid, but could not find anything about this from the API. Could someone kindly confirm this, and point me some better way for user input validity checking instead of catching the exception?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you try to construct a Key with an invalid urlsafe parameter

```
key = ndb.Key(urlsafe='bogus123')
```

you will get an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/tim/git/project/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from src.tim import handlers as handlers_
  File "/home/tim/git/project/src/tim/handlers.py", line 42, in <module>
    class ResetHandler(BaseHandler):
  File "/home/tim/git/project/src/tim/handlers.py", line 47, in ResetHandler
    key = ndb.Key(urlsafe='bogus123')
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 212, in __new__
    self.__reference = _ConstructReference(cls, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py", line 142, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 642, in _ConstructReference
    reference = _ReferenceFromSerialized(serialized)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 773, in _ReferenceFromSerialized
    return entity_pb.Reference(serialized)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py", line 1710, in __init__
    if contents is not None: self.MergeFromString(contents)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 152, in MergeFromString
    self.MergePartialFromString(s)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 168, in MergePartialFromString
    self.TryMerge(d)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py", line 1839, in TryMerge
    d.skipData(tt)
  File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py", line 677, in skipData
    raise ProtocolBufferDecodeError, "corrupted"
ProtocolBufferDecodeError: corrupted
```

Interesting here are is

```
File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py", line 773, in _ReferenceFromSerialized
  return entity_pb.Reference(serialized)
```

which is the last code executed in the [key.py module](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py):

```
def _ReferenceFromSerialized(serialized):
  """Construct a Reference from a serialized Reference."""
  if not isinstance(serialized, basestring):
    raise TypeError('serialized must be a string; received %r' % serialized)
  elif isinstance(serialized, unicode):
    serialized = serialized.encode('utf8')
  return entity_pb.Reference(serialized)
```

`serialized` here being the decoded urlsafe string, you can read more about it in the link to the source code.

another interesting one is the last one:

```
File "/opt/google/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py",   line 1839, in TryMerge
```

in the [entity_pb.py module](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py) which looks like this

```
  def TryMerge(self, d):
    while d.avail() > 0:
      tt = d.getVarInt32()
      if tt == 106:
        self.set_app(d.getPrefixedString())
        continue
      if tt == 114:
        length = d.getVarInt32()
        tmp = ProtocolBuffer.Decoder(d.buffer(), d.pos(), d.pos() + length)
        d.skip(length)
        self.mutable_path().TryMerge(tmp)
        continue
      if tt == 162:
        self.set_name_space(d.getPrefixedString())
        continue


      if (tt == 0): raise ProtocolBuffer.ProtocolBufferDecodeError
      d.skipData(tt)
```

which is where the actual attempt to 'merge the input to into a Key' is made.

---

You can see in the source code that during the process of constructing a Key from an urlsafe parameter not a whole lot can go wrong. First it checks if the input is a *string* and if it's not, a `TypeError` is raised, if it is but it's not 'valid', indeed a `ProtocolBufferDecodeError` is raised.

---

> My current experiment shows that statement above will throw ProtocolBufferDecodeError (Unable to merge from string.) exception if the some_user_input is invalid, but could not find anything about this from the API. Could someone kindly confirm this

Sort of confirmed - we now know that also TypeError can be raised.

> and point me some better way for user input validity checking instead of catching the exception?

This is an excellent way to check validity! Why do the checks yourself if the they are already done by appengine? A code snippet could look like this (not working code, just an example)

```
def get(self):
  # first, fetch the user_input from somewhere

  try:
    key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=user_input)
  except TypeError:
    return 'Sorry, only string is allowed as urlsafe input'
  except ProtocolBufferDecodeError:
    return 'Sorry, the urlsafe string seems to be invalid'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and all pointers to the source code, @Tim! That all makes sense now. The only thing I am a little concerned now is  `ProtocolBufferDecodeError` is not publicly documented. I am afraid catching that is equivalent to using an un-documented API and Google might change those internals, e.g. exception type, in the future without breaking spec contract.

Comment: @YingXiong its implementation is [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/net/proto/ProtocolBuffer.py) and it's quite widely used in appengine, so don't expect it to change any time soon. If you are worried about not catching an exception, you could always add an `except` that catches all other exceptions so that if an error occurs that is not `TypeError` or `ProtocolBufferDecodeError`, it is still caught